# Datetime in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm an experience MS-SQL programmer, but new to MySQL.

I create a table:

```
create table temp 
(
    Col1 DateTime NOT NULL
)
```

I try to insert into the table:

```
insert into temp select '1/1/2014';
```

I get an error "Incorrect datetime value".  Last I check, that was a valid date.

Comment: `insert into temp values('2014-01-01')`

Comment: No friggin way.  It HAS to be yyyy-mm-dd in MySQL?

Comment: @JBrune: or `INSERT INTO temp VALUES ( STR_TO_DATE('1/1/2014','%m/%d/%Y'));`  As a string literal to be evaluated as DATE, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP, yes has to be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss format. It can also be without delimiters, `yyyymmdd`, there's some additional leniency, but it's much more likely to be burned by that leniency, than be helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format is not valid when inserted in MySQL. The correct way is to insert it in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `'YY-MM-DD'`

Please see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Comment: Thanks all.  I also find I can say  _SELECT * FROM temp WHERE Col1 < 'potato'_  and it doesn't throw any error.  Learning curve for me to say the least.

Comment: @JBrune: In a numeric context, `'potato'` evaluates to zero. Try `SELECT 'potato' + 0`.